# Node Red Dashboard File / Event Viewer

Tags: node.js

I am looking to intergrate a log viewer for my alarm system.
Currently it is setup to log events to a file and appended with a new line for each event (Ie "Alarm: Door Open: 12/03/18 at 23:00:00"). Ideally I would like to see the last ~50 events on the dashboard, but I'm unsure how to read the last 50 lines and display them.

Could someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exec node with command:

```
tail -n 50 <name of your log file>
```

The output of this node can then be directed to a text dashboard node.